# Am I due any compensation for a 30-hour delay of an Air India flight?

Tags: delays, compensation, passenger-rights, air-india

On 18 August 2018, I was travelling on Air India flight 966 (Jeddah-Hyderabad) which left at 23:15. Just 35 minutes after takeoff, the captain announced that, due to a technical problem, we were going to Jeddah as an emergency landing. After landing, they put us in a very bad hotel and, 30 hours later, another flight was arranged. Do I have a right to compensation?

Comment: Maybe discuss this with your travel insurance provider. There should be a clause about this in your insurance document.

Comment: What's said about this subject in Air India's Terms of Carriage?

Comment: You may be due some compensation but getting it is another matter.  I could not get any response out of customer services.

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, you should be due some form of compensation by Air India for a 30-hour delay. Indeed, [their conditions of carriage state](http://www.airindia.in/Images/pdf/Conditions_Carriage.pdf):

> ## Article 11 - REFUNDS
>
> ### 11.1 GENERAL
>
> On failure by Carrier to provide carriage in accordance with the Contract of carriage, or where the passenger requests a voluntary change of his or her arrangements, refund for an unused ticket or portion thereof shall be made by Carrier in accordance with this Article and with Carrier’s Regulations.
>
> ### 11.2 PERSON TO WHOM REFUND WILL BE MADE
>
> 11.2.1 Except as herein after provided in this Article, Carrier shall be entitled to make refund either to the person named in the ticket, or to the person who has paid for the ticket upon presentation of satisfactory proof. In the even payment for the
>   ticket is made through a travel agent, refund shall normally be made through such travel agent.
>
> 11.2.2 If a ticket has been paid for by a person other than the passenger named in the ticket, and Carrier has indicated on the ticket that there is a restriction on refund, Carrier shall make a refund only to the person paying for the ticket or to that person’s order.
>
> 11.2.3 Except in the case of lost tickets, refunds will only be made on surrender to Carrier of the passenger coupon or passenger receipt and surrender of all unused flight coupons.
>
> 11.2.4 A refund made to anyone presenting the passenger coupon on passenger receipt and all unused flight coupons and holding himself or herself out as a person to whom refund may be made in terms of 11.2.2 shall be deemed a proper refund and shall discharge Carrier from liability and any further claim for refund.
>
> ### 11.3 INVOLUNTARY REFUNDS
>
> If Carrier cancels a flight, fails to operate a flight reasonable according to schedule, fails to stop at a point to which the passenger is destined or ticketed to stop over, is unable to provide previously confirmed space or causes the passenger to miss a connecting flight on which the passenger holds a reservation, the amount of the refunds shall be:
>
> 11.3.1 If no portion of the ticket has been used, an amount equal to the fare paid;
>
> 11.3.2 If a portion of the ticket has been used, the refund will be the higher of;
>
> 11.3.3 The one way fare (less applicable discounts and charges) from point of interruption to destination or point of next stopover, or
>
> 11.3.4 The difference between the fare paid and the fare for the transportation used.
>
> ### 11.4 VOLUNTARY REFUNDS
>
> If the passenger wishes a refund of his or her ticket for reasons other than those set out in Paragraphs of this Article the amount of the refund shall be:
>
> 11.4.1 If a portion of the ticket has been used, the refund will be an amount equal to the difference between the fare paid and the applicable fare for travel between the points for which the ticket has been used, less any applicable service charges or cancellation fees.

You should probably [get in touch with Air India](http://www.airindia.in/customer-support.htm) themselves to see how to claim the refund. However, actually getting the refund might be harder than expected. The internet is scattered with stories of people trying to claim a refund on Air India flights without success.

Comment: I tried this a few years ago.  They just totally ignored me.

Comment: @badjohn Yes unfortunately whilst the EU regulates passenger rights somewhat properly, other countries do not. There are a gazillion services out there which, for a fee, take care of pestering the airline until you get some form of compensation. Next time, you might want to consider this option.

Comment: Next time, I won't use Air India.

Comment: @badjohn That works too.